# looping through a generic list with foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm trying to learn about generics, and I'm trying to make my own generic list class.

The thing is that I don't know how to get around default(T);

```
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        T current = data[forIndex];
        while (!current.Equals(default(T)))
        {     
            yield return current;
            forIndex++;
            current = data[forIndex];                
        }
        forIndex = 0;
    }
```

This construction means that it will stop iterating through my list if it contains the value 0, since default(T) is 0. Can anyone tell me how to get around this?

Comment: Why do you want to compare with default(T) at all? What is your intention?

Comment: I want to loop through the list with a foreach and write everything in the list out to the console. But I need to know when there is no more valid values to write out. Thats why I'm looking for default(T) since it's the default value. But if I add the value 0 to the list by myself it will also be tagged as default(T), and thats my problem

Comment: If you have a null (or 0) in your collection, why would you *not* want to iterate that element?

Comment: lets say my list is the size of 10. And I have added 1,2,3 to index 0,1,2. Then I dont want to iterate though the last 7 nulls and write those out to my console.

Comment: Why would it have a size of 10 if you only added 3 items? Is that count or capacity? If it's a `List<int>` with count 10, then all members will be initialized by default with `default(int)` or 0. If it simply has capacity 10, then it will only have count 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistake is that you rely on the fact that the internal array only has default values at the end, not in the valid data range. This assumption can be false for any element type (0 for ints, null for ref types. You can store nulls in a `List<string>` for example).

So you can't use this technique.

Instead, I recommend that you keep the current count of items in an integer field. That way you can implement your iterator correctly. Like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < this.count; ++i) //iterating over this.count elements
  yield return data[i];
```

(Some code taken from another answer).

Now, if you insist to do it your way, you can do this:

```
while (current != null)
```

This works even if current is of type T and T is unconstrained. If T is a value type the condition is always true (because a value type would be boxed first and any boxed value is != null).

Comment: Thx ;) I'll make a counter to keep track of it. Didn't think about that at all.

Comment: You could also use linq: `return data.Take(this.count).ToArray().GetEnumerator();` (or ToList rather than ToArray).  This will break down, however, if you want your collection to throw an exception if it's modified while being iterated.

Comment: @usr (previous version of this comment was ambiguous): if you don't call ToArray() or ToList(), you won't get a snapshot of the list when you call `MyOwnList<T>.GetEnumerator()` -- you'll get a delayed-execution linq query.  This could cause problems.  You have to call `GetEnumerator()` on `data.Take(this.count)` because it is `IEnumerable<T>`, but you need to return `IEnumerator<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are holding the data in an array, just iterate it and yield each iteration:

```
for(int i=0; i < data.Length; ++i)
{
  yield return data[i];
}
```